# How can I open location setting by flutter using android_intent

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I open location setting as image below by using android_intent or url_launcher?

[image]

I tried some ways but it did not work:

Example:

```
final AndroidIntent intent = new AndroidIntent(
  action: 'action_view',
  package: 'android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS'
);
intent.launch();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `android_intent` package but the action is incorrect, you have to use this :

```
    final AndroidIntent intent = new AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS',);
    intent.launch();
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS

Comment: Thank for your suggestion and it works. I can know how to use this plugin effective now.

Comment: @diegoveloper Is there something similar for iOS too?

Answer (score 3):

You also can do it without additional dependencies like `android_intent` or `url_launcher`

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL = "com.myapp/intent"
        const val MAP_METHOD = "settings"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
        MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == MAP_METHOD) {
                startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
                result.success(null)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if dart code:

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('com.myapp/intent');

void openSettings() async {
    await platform.invokeMethod('settings');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For both iOS and Android platforms, you can use the `app_settings` plugin - https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings